# Turn into gibberish when I use tab, and up,right,left,down keys

Tags: macos, terminal

it seems that osx has updated to Sierra recently,and I am one of the ones face strange problems. When I was using terminal and want to use tab for autocomplete however it turns out to the blank space like the following picture line3, and when I use direction keys just like right key it will turns out to be ^[[C[image]

This really make me confused and block my convenience, can someone tell me how to sovlve it,THX you very much

Comment: Perhaps your shell is `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`.

Comment: oh!! I got it!!! THX you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you happen to be running in `/bin/sh` (even if the real program is bash) that will act like the POSIX shell, which has no autocompletion or command-history.